# Generate POCO classes in one file with DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

My only experience thus far with EF is a Legacy EF4.0 project in which the POCO classes were all generated in one CS file. This allowed one to add Partial Classes in the same folder with the EDMX, tt, etc files.

I just generated new POCO classes from EF5 using DbContext and I noticed that each class is in it's own file.

I dug into the TT file and I understand why it's doing it:

```
foreach (var entity in typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate<EntityType>(itemCollection))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");
...
```

Is there a setting somewhere that I can modify so that these POCO classes are generated in one file, or am I going to have to modify the TT file to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the call to StartNewFile, but why whould you? Is it required to have it in one file because for partial classes to work correctly the only thing matters is that the namespaces are the same and that both class definitions are in the same assembly. The folder structure does not matter.